# How to import local scripts into jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have some local scripts that are referenced in my index.html. As a result, my react components can access it globally without needing a proper definition.

During unit testing , it fails with undefined reference because it isn't imported.
The module in question is Kendo ui and is kept locally. How do I make kendo a global reference?

I attempted the following, as this worked for global jquery reference in my setupTests file.

```
import * as kendo from '../public/scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js';
global.kendo = kendo;
```

However, the unit test just seems to hang and does not run.

The code calls it by

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
return new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({...options});
```